# No puedo importar modelo en ruta typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, model

PD: Aparte de la info de abajo aquí teneis el source: https://github.com/jsalasdev/hookap-sv

La pregunta es, ¿por qué no puedo acceder a **"User"** que es un modelo para mongoose desde una ruta?

Así tengo el router.

[image: Router]

Como podéis ver User me da error "Cannot find name 'User'" dice.

El modelo User está así.

[image: User model]

Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: puedes agregar el codigo en vez de imagen

Comment: He añadido el repositorio del código

Comment: asi no funciona la red stackoverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] podras ganar unas medallas!!, tambien te invito a leer[como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIÓN EN ESTE HILO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379788/classes-and-interfaces-to-write-typed-models-and-schemas-of-mongoose-in-typescri

Me faltaba tener una interfaz en ts.